# Entity graph on many-to-many relation loading entities multiple times - Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I have @ManyToMany relationship between two of my entities. When I try to load the parents with their children, the parents repeat in response payload. I want to solve my problem with `EntityGraphs`.

Here is the parent with annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Parent_table")
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Parent.children",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("children"))

public class Parent implements Serializable{

//some extra code

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="join table", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="key"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="key"))
private List<Child> children;
```

Here is the code in repository for parent.

```
    @EntityGraph(value = "Parent.children", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
public List<Parent> findAll(Predicate predicate);
```

I have many to many relationship between two of my entities. But I want to get result like

```
parent1 {
child1,
child2
}
```

But I am getting parents for each combination..

```
Parent1 {
child1,
child2
}

Parent1 {
child1,
child2
}
```

there I get parent2.

But what I want is to get the parent1 only once, not repeating.
While using entity graph.

Comment: *the parents repeat in response payload.* What so you mean by "response payload"? If you're talking about a JSON representation then  `@EntityGraph` isn't going to help you with that.

Comment: By response payload, I mean the output that I am getting as JSON. I get each combination of parents multiple times(equal to the number of children)

Answer (score 1):

If you use an [entity graph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/), Hibernate joins the parent and the child table in the query. This creates a product in the result set and you get a reference to the parent entity for each of its children.

You can fix using the `DISTINCT` keyword in your query. With Spring Data JPA, you can do that in 2 ways:

1. You can change the method name from `findAll` to `findAllDistinctBy`.
2. You can define your own query using `@Query("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM parent p")`

Hibernate will include the DISTINCT keyword in your SQL query. You can avoid that by setting the [query hint `QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` to `false`](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-apply-distinct-to-jpql-but-not-sql-query/).

Comment: No property findDistinctAll found for type ServiceBundle! 
I am getting this when I am trying to use findDistinctAll

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It has to be findAllDistinctBy.

I also updated my response.

Comment: Your blogs did help me out so much and thanks for all those material you provide at your website.

BTW 
public List<Parent> listAll() {
Predicate p = null;
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Parent> lst = repo.findAllDistinctBy(p);
log.debug("DB Time to list parents = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
return lst;
 }

what should I do to list all parents only once?

Comment: I don't understand your question. 
Doesn't your code return a List that contains all parents only once?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please look at added information in the end.